# Firebase not uploading file after deleting folder from storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I've recently exceeded my firebase storage and hence, it stopped working. To solve this, I've deleted all files from the storage by completely deleting the first folder that comes in view when clicking the storage button from the console. Surprise surprise, when attempting to load video files from my app again, it no longer works, instead displaying the error below.
I am suspecting it has something to do with not being able to find the reference. 
My question is how can I fix this. Im my app, I am uploading to straight to `Storage.storage().reference()` using `.putFile`. If this is not the correct reference, how can I create a new one?

This is how I'm trying to upload the video to my storage:

```
let USER_STORAGE = Storage.storage().reference()

/// Uploads a video to database using the URL
    private func uploadVideoToDatabase(videoURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool)->Void){
        let filename = videoURL.absoluteString
        USER_STORAGE.child(filename).putFile(from: videoURL, metadata: nil){(metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                completion(false)
            } else {
                completion(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

> video could not be uploaded at this time Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={object=file:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ ... more stuff...NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response., ResponseErrorDomain=NSURLErrorDomain, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com

Comment: Have you checked the server response? Or have you found a way to check the error code?

Comment: @Bright Future I'm don't know how to check the server errors, but my server does nothing upon this request

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Storage has limits for more than just the amount of data stored. There are limits for GB stored, GB downloaded, upload operations, and download operations. I suspect that you surpassed more than 1 GB download/day. You can see more of the limits here https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: I wish it was that, but it's not, I know for a fact because I just checked my usage. I did however have a problem with not being able to delete my storage files, and the console  was saying that I have exceeded my limit. However, the guys at firebase fixed that for me like yesterday, but now, I am not able to upload files anymore

Comment: Are you not able to upload the files directly in the firebase console or via your app? If its via the app, could you share some code?

Comment: Jan not able to upload the files directly via my app. Yes, see my edit

Comment: There might be several reasons why it might not be working. There might be an issue with the url so print the url you are using to the console, and see that there isn't any obvious issues. Make sure that the user is authenticated (I'd sign in with another user and make sure that user is authenticated and see if it works or not). If the user is not authenticated, Firebase won't allow them to upload files.

Comment: I just realized, I am also getting another and I think it might be related to my problem. Here's my error, Let me know what you think. An error occurred on the xpc connection: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.nsurlsessiond" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.nsurlsessiond}